# Jquery Mobile - Navigate internal page no response

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

When I clicked the link alert "optionX" showed but the page does not navigates to the edit page(internal page). I tried

```
$.mobile.changePage("#option", {transition: "slide"});
```

and it didn't work. This supposed to be a simple task but I stucked for a long time for this.

HTML

```
<!-- Start of word page -->
<div data-role="page" id="word">

<div data-role="content">           
    <a href="#option" id='X' >Option</a>        
</div>  
</div><!--End Word page -->

<!-- Start of option page -->
<div data-role="page" id="option">
    <div data-role="content">
       <h1>Option PAGE</h1>
    </div>
</div><!--End option page -->
```

JS PAGE

```
$("a#X").live('click', function(){
    alert('optionX');   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about? Is the DOM definitely ready when the javascript is executed?

```
$("a[id='X'").on('click', function(){
    alert('optionX');   
});
```